# Display a row for each month in a range defined by two columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

This is a example of the table I have:

```
Part No  | Start Date | End Date  |Cost
ABCD1    | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-01|50.99
BDE2     | 2014-01-01 | 2014-03-01|14.59
ABCD1    | 2014-04-13 | 2014-05-01|13.99
```

And this is the output I want to see

```
Part No  | Start Date | End Date  |Cost   |Period
ABCD1    | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-01|50.99  |2014/01
ABCD1    | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-01|50.99  |2014/02
ABCD1    | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-01|50.99  |2014/03
BDE2     | 2014-01-01 | 2014-03-01|14.59  |2014/01
BDE2     | 2014-01-01 | 2014-03-01|14.59  |2014/02
ABCD1    | 2014-04-13 | 2014-05-01|13.99  |2014/04
```

I want to add certain number of rows depending of the range of dates. Also, in each row add the column period that is basically a month and year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest creating a dates table and cross-joining that table to your parts table, something like the following example.

Do this in `tempdb` to not step on anything else.

```
USE tempdb;
```

Create a `Months` table, with the Year, Month, and a starting date for each:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Months
(
    iYear int NOT NULL
    , iMonth int NOT NULL
    , dDate date NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT pk_Months
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        (iYear, iMonth)
);
```

Use a CTE to populate rows into the table above.  This example creates years/months in the range of 1900-01-01 to 2173-10-01:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT v.Num
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))v(Num)
)
, cteDates AS 
(
    SELECT dDate = DATEADD(DAY, 0, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c1.Num))
    FROM cte c1
        CROSS APPLY cte c2
        CROSS APPLY cte c3
        CROSS APPLY cte c4
        CROSS APPLY cte c5
)
, cteMonths AS
(
    SELECT iYear = DATEPART(YEAR, cteDates.dDate)
        , iMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, cteDates.dDate)
    FROM cteDates
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Months(iYear, iMonth, dDate)
SELECT cteMonths.iYear
    , cteMonths.iMonth
    , DATEFROMPARTS(cteMonths.iYear, cteMonths.iMonth, 1)
FROM cteMonths
GROUP BY cteMonths.iYear
    , cteMonths.iMonth
ORDER BY cteMonths.iYear
    , cteMonths.iMonth;
```

Create the table with the sample "Parts" data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PartCosts
(
    PartNum varchar(10) NOT NULL
    , StartDate date NOT NULL
    , EndDate date NOT NULL
    , Cost decimal(10,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.PartCosts(PartNum, StartDate, EndDate, Cost)
VALUES ('ABCD1', '2014-01-01', '2014-04-01', 50.99)
    , ('BDE2', '2014-01-01', '2014-03-01', 14.59)
    , ('ABCD1', '2014-04-01', '2014-05-01', 13.99);
```

Run the cross-join to get the results you're after:

```
SELECT pc.PartNum
    , pc.StartDate
    , pc.EndDate
    , pc.Cost
    , Period = CONVERT(varchar(7), m.dDate, 111)
FROM dbo.PartCosts pc
    CROSS JOIN dbo.Months m
WHERE pc.StartDate <= m.dDate
    AND pc.EndDate > m.dDate;
```

The results:

```
+---------+------------+------------+-------+---------+
| PartNum | StartDate  |  EndDate   | Cost  | Period  |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+---------+
| ABCD1   | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-01 | 50.99 | 2014/01 |
| ABCD1   | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-01 | 50.99 | 2014/02 |
| ABCD1   | 2014-01-01 | 2014-04-01 | 50.99 | 2014/03 |
| BDE2    | 2014-01-01 | 2014-03-01 | 14.59 | 2014/01 |
| BDE2    | 2014-01-01 | 2014-03-01 | 14.59 | 2014/02 |
| ABCD1   | 2014-04-01 | 2014-05-01 | 13.99 | 2014/04 |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: (Nice. PS `Period` is easier to construct since style 111 already has it in `yyyy/mm/dd` format, so you just need to trim. I once wrote [a handy tip with a cheat sheet](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/) that shows all the formats available under `CONVERT()`.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - thanks for that sweet suggestion - I never think about the atypical date formats in CONVERT.

Comment: Another one as a ready reference is Kalman Toth's
http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Comment: @Bijujose holy wow that hurts my eyes. Was that migrated from geocities?

Comment: The goggles, they do nothing!

Comment: I found an issue, but it was kinda my fault.
For example if I run your code and the StartDate is on 2014-13-01, the period starts on 2014/2 instead of 2014/1

Comment: I fixed by truncating the start date to the first day of the month
I used this: CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), exp, 120) + '-01')

Comment: @Solrac - you need to update your question with the new requirements.  Then I can make a change to my answer that works most effectively.

Comment: @MaxVernon done... I changed 2014-04-01 into 2014-04-13
I already fixed the issue in my side but it would be a good idea to have the new requirement and the new solution for archive. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way to do it. Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE #PartCosts
(
  PartNo    varchar(32)   NOT NULL,
  StartDate date          NOT NULL,
  EndDate   date          NOT NULL,
  Cost      decimal(18,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT #PartCosts(PartNo, StartDate, EndDate, Cost)
VALUES('ABCD1','2014-01-01','2014-04-01',50.99),
      ('BDE2 ','2014-01-01','2014-03-01',14.59),
      ('ABCD1','2014-04-01','2014-05-01',13.99);
```

We just need to generate a range of numbers equal to the biggest month gap:

```
DECLARE @range int;
SELECT @range = MAX(DATEDIFF(MONTH, StartDate, EndDate)) FROM #PartCosts;

;WITH x(x) AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT x+1 FROM x WHERE x <= (@range-1))
SELECT p.PartNo, p.StartDate, p.EndDate, p.Cost, 
  [Period] = CONVERT(char(7), DATEADD(MONTH, x.x, p.StartDate), 111)
FROM x CROSS JOIN #PartCosts AS p
WHERE p.EndDate > DATEADD(MONTH, x.x, p.StartDate)
ORDER BY p.StartDate, p.PartNo
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

The `MAXRECURSION` option is only necessary if you'll have ranges spanning more than 100 months, but better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem you have to unpack the date interval, For this I have used Itzik ben gan's getnum function which you can find here

**http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers**

```
create table #parts (partno varchar(50),startdate datetime,enddate datetime,cost float)


insert into #parts
select 'ABCD1','20140101','20140401',50.99
union all
select 'BDE2','20140101','20140301',14.59
union all
select 'ABCD1','20140401','20140501',13.99



SELECT partno
    ,startdate
    ,enddate
    ,cost
    ,convert(varchar(7),dateadd(mm, b.n, startdate),111) AS period
FROM (
    SELECT datediff(mm, startdate, enddate) AS n
        ,*
    FROM #parts
    ) x
CROSS APPLY dbo.getnums(n) b
DROP TABLE #parts
```

also I have made the getnum function to start from index 0, added a select to include 0 ,modified version
here

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNums](@n AS BIGINT) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  WITH
  L0   AS(SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
  L2   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
  L3   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
  L4   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
  L5   AS(SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
  Nums AS(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 0)
  SELECT TOP (@n) n FROM Nums ORDER BY n;
```

NB: please test the code before run